# How to test route in symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes

In Kohana You can test routes like this

```
$route = Route::get('admin');
echo Kohana_Debug::dump($route->matches('admin/user/edit/10'));
```

and how can I test routes in symfony2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try console commands ? Take a look at the documentation page [documentation page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#visualizing-debugging-routes)

```
php app/console router:debug
php app/console router:debug article_show
php app/console router:match /blog/my-latest-post
```